# Cef Sharp not displaying pdf file into browser window

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, cefsharp

I've build an application using `CefSharp.WinForms`.
All is good but when any website uses to show PDF it'll show a blank page.
Can any one help me how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: What version are you using? Does the problem reproduce using the `MinimalExample`? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample Does the `PDF` file open in `Chrome`? Check the `Debug.log` file in your bin directory for error messages.

Comment: Current version `Chromium: 43.0.2357.130, CEF: r3.2357.1287.g861c26e, CefSharp: 43.0.0.0, Environment: x86`
PDF working fine with given example `Chromium: 47.0.2526.80, CEF: r3.2526.1362.g26b3a7a, CefSharp: 47.0.2.0, Environment: x64`

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1144

Comment: worked only for one time, after that always troughs error `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess has stopped working`

Comment: If you can, upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: I've upgraded to latest version, and it's working. Thanks

Comment: chromium browser not displaying javascript popups, can you help me with this. 
I've already implemented ILifeSpanHandler it is working very fine with links but fails when popup is opened through javascript. not even calling OnBeforePopup

Comment: What do you define as a javascript popup? A window opened using javascript? Usually best to ask a separate question rather in the comments.